# After updating Blender from 2.79 to 2.81, all my bones don't work as they should

Tags: armature, bones

So all my models are the same. When I try to rotate a bone in pose mode, the mesh kinda rotates faster than the bone. But if I make a new object using the same armature and weight paint it and all that, it works fine.

Here's a video of what happens https://youtu.be/kfsslGc6mSg, and the Christmas hat is a new object.

Comment: Can you provide the blend file?

Comment: here's a link https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArmH8FmzXuqpgaFDLPFXMGX32GDJNA?e=1zlOI4 to a onedrive folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the Rigid Body simulation.

[image]

It is good to Apply Object Transform

[image]

and parent the character to the armature,

[image]

so it will follow it.

[image]

I recommend you to transfer the character to the new blend file to get rid of the legacy scene settings.

[image]